# invalid_grant error with valid SAML2.0 assertion on SalesForce

Tags: java, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I'm tried to implement SSO for SalesForce using OpenSAML. My code generates valid SAML assertion, which validated by salesforce SAML validator. But when I tried to send assertion to salesforce I always got this error:

```
{"error_uri":"https://na4.salesforce.comnull/setup/secur/SAMLValidationPage.apexp","error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"}
```

I using folloving code to send request to salesforce:

```
    SAMLResponseGenerator responseGenerator = new SalesforceSAMLResponseGenerator(container, strIssuer, strNameID, strNameQualifier, sessionId);

    String samlAssertion = Base64.encodeBase64String(responseGenerator.generateSAMLAssertionString());
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entity.addPart("grant_type", new StringBody("assertion"));
        entity.addPart("assertion_type", new StringBody("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser"));
        entity.addPart("assertion", new StringBody(samlAssertion));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
        rd.close();
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My generator generated valid SAML (If I can trust salesforce SAML validator results).
Seems that salesforce can't decode assertion, because when I sent random data instead of samlAssertion I've recieved same error message.

I also tried to use Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString() to encode but without positive results.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of my problem was very simple. Do not trust SalesForce's documents, trust only [protocol specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf) :)
According to specs I needs to send Base64 encoded SAML in SAMLResponse parameter. That is all.

I've using following code illustrated the solution:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = initHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://login.salesforce.com/");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
    entity.addPart("SAMLResponse", new StringBody(Base64.encodeBase64String(samlAssertion)));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    Header location = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Location");
    if (null != location) {
        System.out.println(location.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Did same in my code, using HttpClient and HttpPost, but receiving same error